# Error using SQL Server 2019 Import and Export Data (64-bit)

Tags: sql-server, errors, sql-server-2019

I'm getting an error immediately upon starting the SQL Server 2019 Import and Export (64-bit) wizard, and I'm looking for ideas.  The error is:

```
The SSIS Data Flow Task could not be created. Verify that the DTSPipeline.dll is available and registered. The wizard cannot continue and it will terminate.

Additional information:

Cannot create a task from XML for task "", type ", {D9DA2996-AD06-4166-9C0C-C53E29834AF2}" due to error 0xC0000002 "".
 ({50E060E2-93A0-4F72-9DB6-F692E561312A})
```

A screen shot of the error is below.

I have tried everything I can think of or find online, including:

- register DTSPipeline.dll and DTS.dll with regsvr32 from the 150 folder
- install latest CU of SQL Server 2019
- repair SQL Server 2019 using the installer
- uninstall everything that mentions SQL Server from the control panel
- re-install SQL Server 2019 after uninstalling everything
- try again prior to installing latest CU
- try again after installing latest CU after re-install of SQL Server 2019
- try with Run As Administrator
- re-install Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe
- install latest SSMS

Nothing changes it. Even after totally removing SQL Server 2019 and re-installing.

I can't think of what else to try.

[image]

[image]

SSIS is installed

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Could you click on the **Show details** button in the error message and post the details in your question? Hit [edit] and add the details directly underneath the screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use -  I added the error details, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying from this a client machine pointing to a SQL Server instance or are you running this from the SQL Server instance server ? Which version of SSMS are you using ?

Comment: @armitage It is all running on the same system, a Windows 10 Pro system, all services. It is running SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition.  SSMS is version 18.7.  It also has VS 2019 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm interesting it's calling out SSIS. This is just going out in a limb, but can you use the SQL installer to ensure SSIS is installed and then retry: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Hopefully that fixes the underlying issue.

Comment: SSIS is installed (added a screen shot in my original post).

Comment: Is the Windows service for SSIS currently running? Click Start -> Run -> type services and then look for SQL Server Integration Services and verify the Status says "Running".

Comment: Yes, it is running. And I've also tried running it as the user the SQL Server installer creates and as LocalSystem.

Comment: Yea I think you unfortunately have a very specific odd issue. You might have to reach out to Microsoft for help with this one. The only other thing I can think of is when you registered DTSPipeline.dll and DTS.dll with regsvr32, did you do it from the command line running as administrator mode?

Comment: Yes, I did do it using Run as Administrator (started Command Prompt using Run As Administrator)